# use same function for multiple file upload events

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js, js-xlsx

I have used js-xlsx plugin to parse JSON from an excel file. I am parsing JSON from multiple excel files and I want to use the same parsing function to load the result in multiple dropdowns. I have two upload file inputs and two corresponding dropdowns. I am able to get the `xlFileName`  and `sheetNames` only for the first dropdown. If I want to upload a different excel file using the second file upload input and want to load the `xlFileName`  and `sheetNames` for the corresponding excel file in the second dropdown  how can I use the same JS functions to achieve this. Thanks in advance. (I have tried switch case to get the ids of upload file inputs but didn't know how to get it done right)

HTML:

```
<input type="file" style="display:none;" name="files" id="inputFile1" />
<span data-bind="text: fileNameXl1"></span>
<select id="dropdown3" required="required" class="form-control select2" data-bind="options:xlnames,value:selectedSheetname1, 
                                                 selectedOptions: chosenFile,optionsCaption:'Please Select Sheet Name'">
</select>
<input type="file" style="display:none;" name="files" id="inputFile2" />
<span data-bind="text: fileNameXl1"></span>
<h4 class="header-title m-t-0 m-b-30">Select Sheet name(Macro):</h4>
<select id="dropdown4" required="required" class="form-control select2" data-bind="options:xlnames1,value:selectedSheetname2,
                                                 selectedOptions: chosenFile,optionsCaption:'Please Select Sheet Name'">
</select>
```

JS:

```
self.selectedSheetname1 = ko.observable("");
self.selectedSheetname2 = ko.observable();
self.selectedSheetname3 = ko.observable();
self.chosenFile = ko.observable();
self.xlnames = ko.observableArray([]);
self.xlnames1 = ko.observableArray([]);
self.fileNameXl1 = ko.observable();

self.handleFile = function(e) {
            var files = e.target.files;
            var f = files[0];
            {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                xlFileName = f.name;
                self.fileNameXl1(xlFileName);
                console.log(xlFileName);
                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    if(typeof console !== 'undefined') console.log("onload", new Date());
                    var data = e.target.result;
                    var wb;
                    var arr = fixdata(data);
                    wb = X.read(btoa(arr), {type: 'base64'});
                    process_wb(wb);
                }
            }
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
        };
        self.fixdata = function(data) {
            var o = "", l = 0, w = 10240;
            for(; l<data.byteLength/w; ++l) o+=String.fromCharCode.apply(null,new Uint8Array(data.slice(l*w,l*w+w)));
            o+=String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(data.slice(l*w)));
            return o;
        };
        self.process_wb = function(wb) {
            var output = "";
            output = JSON.stringify(to_json(wb), 2, 2);
            var parse = JSON.parse(output);
            sheetNames = Object.keys(parse);
            console.log("this is output");
            console.log(sheetNames);
            self.xlnames(sheetNames);
            if(typeof console !== 'undefined') console.log("output", new Date());
        };
        self.to_json = function(workbook) {
            var result = {};
            workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
                var roa = X.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
                if(roa.length > 0){
                    result[sheetName] = roa;
                }
            });
            return result;
        };
        self.loadSheetNamesB25 = function(e){
            self.xlnames([]);
            self.handleFile(e);

        };
        self.loadSheetNamesB41 = function(e){
            self.xlnames1([]);
            self.xlnames2([]);
            self.handleFile(e);
        };

if(xlf1.addEventListener) xlf1.addEventListener('change', self.loadSheetNamesB25, false);
if(xlf2.addEventListener) xlf2.addEventListener('change', self.loadSheetNamesB41, false);
```